# Rails Find By Token Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model that looks like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :generate_token

  def to_param
    token
  end

  private

  def generate_token

    self.token = loop do
       random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10, false)
       break random_token unless Product.exists?(token: random_token)
    end
  end

end
```

My routes looks like:

```
get "products/:token" => "products#show"
```

and my controller looks like:

```
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(token: params["token"])
end
```

But I get the error: `Unknown key: token`, even though the token is definitely getting created (it shows in the url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  @product = Product.find_by(token: params["token"])
```

`find` method always expects id.

Comment: use key in params `params[:token]`

Comment: @PhilidorGreen - It is not necessary, params are created with indifferent access.

Comment: `params` variable always be hash with indifferent access?

Comment: It is rails controller, if he didn't override `params` method it has indifferent access.